# How do I set up TLS for Slack Alerts Messaging in Grafana?

Tags: docker, grafana, slack, grafana-alerts

I set up my alert rule and notification policy in grafana v10.0.01 to send a slack message when a certain metric exceeds a threshold. The alert rule is firing but when the notification policy attempts to send the Slack message, it returns the following error message:

```
failed to send Slack message: failed to send request: Post <personal_slack_webhook>: tls failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I set up a slack webhook to make post requests to in order to send messages. I was able to send messages from the command line on my host system. .

I tried reading through the documentation for any guidance on setting up TLS for alerts but there weren't any pages I could find. I looked in forums for similar issues but none of them matched my specific situation, as I'm running grafana in a docker container with a Prometheus data source. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This looks like not a Slack related issue: their TLS certificates are fine.

I suppose there is a problem with your docker container, check this thread [How to resolve tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority while building a go dockerfile in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75696690/how-to-resolve-tls-failed-to-verify-certificate-x509-certificate-signed-by-un)

I.e. your host machine is able to make outbound requests separately from docker container and vice-versa: trusted certificates from host machine are in a separate scope than certificates inside the container.

You could add host machine certificates to a docker container like it is described there, or try to replace docker image with another one: try to use a full-featured image like ubuntu/debian/centos-based instead of alpine or other "minimized" distributions. I suppose the image should have contents of installed `ca-certificates` package or analogues.